# apex manage users and groups directly on application

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm newbie on apex, and made an application that demands the app admin to insert users - in customized groups, on apex workspace - **Manage Users and Groups**. My application uses Authorization Schemes based on these customised groups, instead of create an Access Control List. I guess this is more useful, because It's could be possible to make more and different groups, and more flexible access control of pages, reports, buttons etc. But this kind of implementation could bring some security issues on my office. I wonder if is possible to create a page that refers, and also mantains (CRUD) to this workspace users, at workspace groups?

Comment: I haven't done this, but you probably can using the various API procedures in the APEX_UTIL package: create_user, create_user_group, edit_user etc.

Comment: Well, I have found the solution for this, at https://community.oracle.com/thread/3772429  changing the security attributes on shared components, database session. But was yielded a new issue. After create a procedure to create a user, I attach a form on a procedure that raises the ORA 01400 ERROR. My form is fully provided of information, but yet calls this error: ORA-01400: it's not possible insert NULL at ("APEX_050000"."WWV_FLOW_FND_USER"."USER_NAME").

Comment: create or replace procedure "CREATEUSER"
(user_name IN VARCHAR2,
first_name IN VARCHAR2,
last_name IN VARCHAR2,
temp_passwd IN VARCHAR2,
group IN VARCHAR2)
is
BEGIN
 APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER(
        p_user_name                     => user_name,
        p_first_name                    => first_name,
        p_last_name                     => last_name,
        p_web_password                  => 'temp_passwd
        p_default_schema                => 'myschema',
        p_change_password_on_first_use  => 'Y',
        p_group_ids                     => group);
END;

Comment: I'm a little closer, but I'm getting ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APEX_050000"."WWV_FLOW_FND_USER"."WEB_PASSWORD_VERSION") which is interesting since there is no parm for WEB_PASSWORD_VERSION in the api!

Comment: Got past my error; I mis-typed my password field name :(